# Menu names not getting translated

Tags: theme-development, menus, themes, translation, localization

I've got the following code in a theme to register two menus:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
  'primary'   => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'text-domain' ),
  'secondary' => esc_html__( 'Secondary', 'text-domain' )
) );
```

There is a French translation that is working for ALL other text in the theme except for these two strings. The English "Primary" and "Secondary" are still displayed in the Menus page instead.

Has anyone experienced anything like this? I've tried changing the menu IDs and names, but for some reason it still won't translate.

Comment: `text-domain` is real text domain or dummy?

Comment: Ensure that the current language has been set and text domain loaded BEFORE register_nav_menus is called. Common mistake is to hook in too early.